# PHP GD imagecreatefromstring discards transparency

Tags: php, php-gd

I've been trying to get transparency to work with my application (which dynamically resizes images before storing them) and I think I've finally narrowed down the problem after much misdirection about `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha`. The source image is never loaded with proper transparency!

```
// With this line, the output image has no transparency (where it should be
// transparent, colors bleed out randomly or it's completely black, depending
// on the image)
$img = imagecreatefromstring($fileData);
// With this line, it works as expected.
$img = imagecreatefrompng($fileName);

// Blah blah blah, lots of image resize code into $img2 goes here; I finally
// tried just outputting $img instead.

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagealphablending($img, FALSE);
imagesavealpha($img, TRUE);
imagepng($img);

imagedestroy($img);
```

It would be some serious architectural difficulty to load the image from a file; this code is being used with a JSON API that gets queried from an iPhone app, and it's easier in this case (and more consistent) to upload images as base64-encoded strings in the POST data. Do I absolutely ***need*** to somehow store the image as a file (just so that PHP can load it into memory again)? Is there maybe a way to create a Stream from `$fileData` that can be passed to `imagecreatefrompng`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue on `PHP 5.3.10 / GD 2.0`, Working fine. What versions are you using ? Might come from something else.. Corrupted PNG entry ? Like iPhone app uploading a bad quality image ? Just shots in the dark

Comment: I tested this on `PHP 5.3.16-1~dotdeb.0` (with Suhosin) with `GD 2.0.34` (2.0.34 compatible) on my Debian box, and when I ran `imagepng` the transparent parts were black.  This happened when I used `imagecreatefromstring` or `imagecreatefrompng`.

Comment: I'm in PHP 5.3.10 /  GD (2.0.34 compatible).

Comment: Edit: I didn't test this with `imagealphablending` or `imagesavealpha`.

Comment: Found this, not sure if it helps: http://theolagendijk.com/2009/10/24/php-imagepng-transparant-turns-black/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blech, this turned out to ultimately be due to a totally separate GD call which was validating the image uploads. I forgot to add `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` to THAT code, and it was creating a new image that then got passed to the resizing code. Which should probably be changed anyway. Thanks very much to goldenparrot for the excellent method of converting a string into a filename.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this code :

```
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// preserve transparency

imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127));

imagealphablending($new, false);

imagesavealpha($new, true);

imagecopyresampled($new, $img, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);

imagepng($new);

imagedestroy($new);
```

It will make a transparent image for you. Good Luck !

Comment: This put it all together for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I absolutely need to somehow store the image as a file (just so that PHP can load it into memory again)?

No.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) says:

You can use `data://` protocol from php v5.2.0

Example:

```
// prints "I love PHP"
echo file_get_contents('data://text/plain;base64,SSBsb3ZlIFBIUAo=');
```

Comment: You should be able to do `$img = imagecreatefrompng('data://image/png;base64,'.$base64Image);`